# Setting an accessible character encoding

Tags: font-encodings, accessibility

I'm using pdflatex/Overleaf for my thesis, and running an accessibility check with Foxit PDF Editor. Below is part of the result:

[image]

Ignoring tagging for now, right now I'm trying to fix the character encoding error above. The documentation for the error states:

> A correct character encoding is required to display readable text in
> software/hardware. To fix the issue, you need to check whether the
> necessary fonts have been installed on your system or re-create the
> PDF from a file that uses a proper font (preferably OpenType).

Best I can tell, I'm using the default fonts, flavors of Computer Modern, embedded in the PDF:

[image]

But I'm not sure exactly what I need to do here to set the character encoding in a way this tool expects. I've tried setting both the following without result:

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfencoding=unicode
  % Neither of these (by themselves) seem to help
  pdfencoding=pdfdoc
}
```

I'm thinking that since the character encoding error is happening 1612 times, it must be a element-level issue not a document-level one, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've also done a little digging into what it would take to change to an OpenType font, but I'm a little uncertain if it would be worth the effort/risk/reward at this late stage of the thesis approval process, or if it would even solve the problem.

Comment: My plan is to fix as much of these errors as I can manage in LaTeX and then do the hard parts like tagging manually in Foxit.

Comment: For opentype font you have to switch to XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: try with `\input{glyphtounicode} \pdfgentounicode=1 `  in your preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, that seems to have solved that item.